# can't change to sudoers.d directory

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, command

Simple question: I have a user called "user" on my system. This user has sudo privileges. Why can't I browse into the sudoer.d directory then?

Is it because cd is a built-in command?

```
[user@localhost etc]$ ls -al | grep sudoers.d
drwxr-x---.  2 root root   4096 Apr  4 18:09 sudoers.d
[user@localhost etc]$ sudo cd sudoers.d
[user@localhost etc]$ pwd
/etc
[user@localhost etc]$ sudo ls -la sudoers.d/
total 12
drwxr-x---.  2 root root 4096 Apr  4 18:09 .
drwxr-xr-x. 79 root root 4096 May  5 05:20 ..
-r--r-----.  1 root root   33 Apr  4 18:09 vagrant
[user@localhost etc]$ sudo vim sudoers.d/vagrant
[user@localhost etc]$
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you need `+x` permission to `cd` to a directory...

Comment: `sudo cd` is meaningless. `cd` is shell builtin. `sudo` is an external command.

Comment: You should get an error when you try to sudo cd as it is a builtin...

Comment: @123: I clearly didn't get any error. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because `sudo` simply executes the command executable you pass to it with elevated privileges, and forwards the rest of arguments. Since `cd` is a shell builtin, sudo won't find the file to execute, which results in an error.

If you wish to have an interactive shell with elevated privileges, use `sudo su`

Comment: `Your cd command changes the working directory of that subshell`, no it doesn't

Comment: true, answer updated

Comment: @Géza Török: "sudo won't find the file to execute, which results in an error."

When I do "sudo cd sudoers.d" I am not getting any error as seen above.

Comment: @miticoluis: On my debian:
# sudo cd ..
sudo: cd: command not found

Comment: @miticoluis: Anyway, regardless of sudo being actually able to execute the cd command or not, it's still encapsulated and therefore won't affect your shell's environment.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` opens a new shell. That shell changes its working directory. And then it exits. The original shell's working directory is never changed, nor can it be.

Comment: `That shell changes its working directory.` Nope, not unless for some odd reason you aren't using the builtin cd.

Comment: @123: bash, at least on my system, includes external binaries with the same name as some the internal commands, `cd` included. Whether or not the do anything... haven't checked.

Comment: What distro are you using ?

Comment: @123: Fedora. They're in the bash package, at the very least.